# Why values within a "Style Box" are discrete and not continuous?

Tags: terminology, portfolio, asset-class

Style Boxes map financial products on a two axes diagram, but instead of using continuous values for the axes, they use discrete values (small/medium/large, value/blend/growth, etc.).

[image]([source](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stylebox.asp))

How is this useful? Why should $1 be able to shift a product between squares? What's wrong with using for example the actual (normalized?) market cap on one axis and the actual (normalized?) P/E ratio on the other axis, in the familiar Cartesian representation?

Comment: To the vote to closer - the question is clear as day. The boxes have 9 choices. And the answer shows the new system is continuous.

Comment: The answer is "because it's a marketing tool".

Answer (score 2):

It appears that in 2016 Morningstar presented [a new framework](http://news.morningstar.com/articlenet/article.aspx?id=774830) for style box based analysis, which is continuous:

[image] ([source](http://news.morningstar.com/articlenet/article.aspx?id=774830))

Another document from 2004 shows a similar continuous nature:

[image] ([source](https://corporate.morningstar.com/US/documents/MethodologyDocuments/FactSheets/MorningstarStyleBox_FactSheet_.pdf))